# Realm query objects by child attribute(RealmList) with in() return all objects

Tags: android, realm

Code

```
public class Chat extends RealmObject {
  private RealmList<Contact> contactsList;
}
public class Contact extends RealmObject {
  private PhoneNumber phoneNumber;
}
public class PhoneNumber extends RealmObject {
  private String number;
}

String tArray[] = new String[]{"234234","234423432","23432423"};
RealmQuery<Chat> realmQuery  = realm.where(Chat.class).in("contactsList.phoneNumber.number",tArray);
RealmResults<Chat> chatList = realmQuery.findAll();
```

This query returns all the objects instead of the ones specified in the array.  Why?

Comment: add primarykey field for all tables and use realm.where(A.class).equalTo("primaryKeyField",value).findFirst(); to retrive specific records and so on..

Comment: What did you intend to get back from that query? Not sure what is meant by "all objects"?